# Pascal - doubly linket list

Tags: list, insert, pascal

I'm trying compile Doubly linked list but I have one small problem with this part of code :

It's a "insert after"

When I insert data to the list : 1 2 3 4 5 and want insert after number 4 for example number 9, number 9 is inserted like this : 1 9 2 3 4 5. I really dont know where I have wrong code:(

everytime i insert new number to second position..

```
procedure insertAfter(var L:Plist; n_p:integer);
var novy_za:Plist;

  begin
    new(novy_za);
    novy_za^.info:=n_p;
    novy_za^.next:=L^.next;
    novy_za^.prev:=L;
    L^.next:=novy_za;
      if novy_za^.next<>nil
      then novy_za^.next^.prev:=novy_za;
 end;
```

procedure call :

```
  begin
   writeln;
   write('which number insert  : '); readln(x);
   writeln;
   write('insert after  : '); readln(Y);
   InsertAfter(P,x);
  end;
```

Comment: Then you're passing the first item to the procedure.

Comment: Your procedure `insertAfter` always inserts after the first element of the list. So of course you will always get the same result: `1 9 2 3 4 5`. How do you want `insertAfter` to decide where to insert? For example, if you want to insert after a specific value, then `insertAfter` needs a parameter giving that value, then the code in that procedure needs to traverse the list until it finds the element with that value, then inserts a new element with the new value after that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a corrected version of your routine. Your original failed to accept the value you want to insert after as an argument. I made it a function so that it returns the pointer to the new added element if it was able to find the one you wanted to insert after. Otherwise, it returns `nil`. You call it with a second argument which tells it what value you want to insert after.

```
function insertAfter(var L: Plist; n_a, n_p: integer): Plist;
var novy_za, cur_za: Plist;
begin
  cur_za := L;
  novy_za := nil;

  { Traverse the list, looking for value n_a and, if found, insert the new
    element n_p after it }

  while cur_za <> nil do begin
    { Insert the new element after the one with value n_a }

    if cur_za^.info = n_a then begin
      new(novy_za);
      novy_za^.info := n_p;
      novy_za^.next := cur_za^.next;
      novy_za^.prev := cur_za;
      cur_za^.next := novy_za;

      if novy_za^.next <> nil then
        novy_za^.next^.prev := novy_za;
      break;       { Exit the loop }
    end;

    cur_za := cur_za^.next;
  end;

  insertAfter := novy_za;
end;
```

Function call (this assumes `P` is defined somewhere as a valid `Plist`, and `x` and `y` are defined as `info` type):

```
begin
  writeln;
  write('which number insert  : '); readln(x);
  writeln;
  write('insert after  : '); readln(y);

  { Insert the value x after the number y }

  if insertAfter(P, y, x) = nil then
    writeln('The value ', y, ' was not found')
  else
    writeln('The value ', x, ' was successfully inserted after ', y);
end;
```